# How to start developing WP8 apps for free?

Tags: apps, store, windows-8

I want to start writing apps for Windows Phone 8 and above.
I went then to their website and wanted to register a developer account. But my options are to register as an Individual ($19) and as a Corporation (above $100). I don't want to spend any money on this. I just want to try it. Is there a way to get those IDs (Publisher GUID and App ID) without publishing my app in the store thus without spending any money?

**Edit:** I AM a student (in Bulgaria) but I use elementaryOS (Linux-based) as my OS, therefore I cannot install Visual Studio. Can @Thomas tell me the exact process of signing up for a free developer account?

Comment: I'd recommend just going through the Windows AppStudio signup process. It's pretty self-explanatory plus you can get started with app development pretty fast.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to get a free developer account for the Windows (Phone) Store:

- Apply for a "Free Dev Center account for unregistered developers" trough the [Dev Center Benefits Program](https://devcenterbenefits.windows.com/)
- Sign up for a free developer account through [Windows AppStudio](https://appstudio.windows.com/de-de/home/appstudio)
- If you are a student you can also get a free developer account through the [DreamSpark Program](https://www.dreamspark.com/)

Comment: Or you can "be a student" if you get yourself a free .edu email account: http://blog.laptopmag.com/how-to-get-an-edu-email-address (obviously I wouldn't release anything to market using that technique)

Comment: well there is really no need to fake being a student if the other legal ways are just as simple to go through - if not easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs#d-express-windows-8), then attempt to deploy the app to your phone, it should automatically take you through getting a license for free. Note that this will only work for deploying apps directly from your PC, not publishing them to the app store.